# Can you make Area Level mandatory down to Level 3?

Tags: azure-boards

We are running ADO Sprint 230, hosted edition.

Say a team is called Team1, and they have a product called WidgetMaker. WidgetMaker has multiple areas; e.g. UI, SOAP API, REST API, Database, Documentation, Deployment etc., and each of these areas has child areas at level 4, 5 or sometimes level 6.

If in the Team1 boards/sprints, when someone creates a bug, the default Area Path is set to `Team1\WidgetMaker`. I want to enforce a change that means they have to set an Area Path to level 3, so they must set `Team1\WidgetMaker\UI` or `Team1\WidgetMaker\API` etcetera.

Is this possible?